# Persistence context lifecycle in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm a bit of confused about **persistence context** and its lifecycle.
Suppose I have a simple **DAO** class such as the following.

```
public class UserDao
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public User getUserById(Integer id)
    {
     return manager.find(User.class, id); 
    }

    public User getUserByName(String name)
    {
        Query q = manager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = ?1");
        q.setParameter(1, name);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> list = (List<User>) q.getResultList();

        if(!list.isEmpty())
         return list.get(0);

        return null;
    }  
}
```

In my understanding each invocation of method on the **EntityManager** is
like a transaction on its own, so a persistence context is created
and closed soon after retrieving results or actuating changes,
and the Entities that are returned are detached.

**Please correct me if I'm wrong.**

Now even if in one of the methods above used the **EntityManager** twice,
two separate persistence contexts would come to play one after another,
is that   right ?

An invocation of **EntityManager** returns managed entities only if the   persistence conext has not already been closed, and that happens when we are in a transaction scope.

It may seem not clear what I'm asking, but I just would like you to validate my   knoledge or provide clrifications, thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: JPQL parameters are either NAMED (:name) or POSITIONAL (?1, ?2). Yours is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The PersistenceContext lives until the EntityManager is closed. When the EntityManager is closed, depends on the scope of the EntityManager and whether it is managed by your application or an JavaEE container. See here for details: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/

Comment: what about the examples i have given ?

Comment: In JavaEE the lifecycle of the EntityManager is managed by the container and therefor is related to JTA. Is your class an EJB?

Comment: no i' m working on tomcat using Spring, it is a repository bean.

Comment: can you validate what i stated?

Comment: There's always a new Persistence Context if there's a new Entity Manager. If you're using Spring transactions there always will be the same EntityManager injected to your bean as long as you're in the same transaction. So the lifecycle of your PersistenceContext will be as long as the lifecycle of your EntityManager which lives as long as the transaction. At least thats the case for JavaEE. I think Spring will handle this the same. So if you're calling your bean in different transactions, you'll get a newly injected EntityManager with its own PersistenceContext.